# Erlang library discovery

Tags: erlang

I'm looking for a service where I can discover new erlang libraries. I know that I can find some in Github or BitBucket, but I was looking for something more specific.

I remember that I had found something like that in the past, but I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be remembering is [EXPM](http://expm.co/) which is discontinued in favor of [Hex](https://hex.pm/).

You could look into [this wiki](https://github.com/0xAX/erlang-bookmarks) with benefit of bookmarks being recommend (used and working).

And [ErlangCentral](https://erlangcentral.org/erlang-projects/) is doing a good work with collecting erlang projects in one place, and [announcing new releases](https://erlangcentral.org/category/news/).  It is also a great place for [newest blog posts](https://erlangcentral.org/erlang-times/) and [videos from conferences](https://erlangcentral.org/category/videos/) which is **the** best way of keeping tabs on what's happening in Erlang work.

Answer (score 1):

[Hex](https://hex.pm/) is a package manager for the Erlang VM. The majority of the packages are written in Elixir, but there are some Erlang packages as well. Hex currently only supports automatic package management for Elixir, but you can still find Erlang packages and find a link to e.g. a Github repository.

You can also call Elixir functions directly in your Erlang code, see [this](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#interop) post.